# Подстановка значений excel

Tags: excel

Есть таблица вида

```
+--------+---------+
| name_1 | value_1 |
| name_2 | value_2 |
| name_3 | value_3 |
+--------+---------+
```

на отдельном `лист_1`.
Хочу получить значение `value` на основе `name` (именно получить, а не вывести в ячейку) на `лист_2`:
допустим в `А1` я введу `name_2`, а в `A2` в уже имеющуюся формулу

```
=time(;VALUE;) //на место VALUE должно быть соответственно
               //значение из вышеупомянутой таблицы
```

нужно подставить соответственно значение `value`.
Какие функции использовать? `vlookup`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непонятно, откуда такая функция *time*, почему в английской локали разделитель параметров точка с запятой...

Наверное, так?

```
 =time(;vlookup(A1;Лист1!$A$1:$B$4;2;);)
```